# Parsing the Stanford dependencies

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I need to get basic relations out of a given text. I found
Stanford dependencies and looked at the first basic example:

```
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");

TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();

String[] sent = new String[]{"vladimir", "putin", "was", "born", "in", "st.", "petersburg", "and", "he", "was", "not", "born", "in", "berlin", "."};
Tree parse = lp.apply(Sentence.toWordList(sent));
GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
Collection<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependencies();

System.out.println(tdl);
```

The result is:

```
[nn(putin-2, vladimir-1), nsubjpass(born-4, putin-2), auxpass(born-4, was-3), root(ROOT-0, born-4), prep(born-4, in-5), nn(petersburg-7, st.-6), pobj(in-5, petersburg-7), cc(born-4, and-8), nsubjpass(born-12, he-9), auxpass(born-12, was-10), neg(born-12, not-11), conj(born-4, born-12), prep(born-12, in-13), pobj(in-13, berlin-14)]
```

A more pretty output:

```
nn(putin-2, vladimir-1)
nsubjpass(born-4, putin-2)
auxpass(born-4, was-3)
root(ROOT-0, born-4)
prep(born-4, in-5)
nn(petersburg-7, st.-6)
pobj(in-5, petersburg-7)
cc(born-4, and-8)
nsubjpass(born-12, he-9)
auxpass(born-12, was-10)
neg(born-12, not-11)
conj(born-4, born-12)
prep(born-12, in-13)
pobj(in-13, berlin-14)
```

My question now is: Is there already a parser which parses the relations?
For example i want to get the relation: "was born in" between "vladimir putin" and "st. petersburg",
so i need the following dependencies:

```
nn(putin-2, vladimir-1)
nsubjpass(born-4, putin-2)
auxpass(born-4, was-3)
prep(born-4, in-5)
nn(petersburg-7, st.-6)
pobj(in-5, petersburg-7)
```

So i have all informations i need. i could write a parser which returns me 
the governal noun, the relation and the dependet noun but if there is already
a parser i dont need to write my own.

So is there any?

Comment: what is the variable "Sentence" ?

Answer (score 0):

Semantic Role Labeling might be useful : 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/srl/

Which finds the relations between spans of text and its triggers (e.g. verbs).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, The problem of extracting relations can be achieved by using

1. Tregex on the constituency parse output (Stanford dependency parser is said to follow this route)
2. Use a dependency parser output such as stanfrod dependency parser. As for parsing the output, you might find the response from Chris. Manning useful
   [Stanford Parser - Traversing the typed dependencies graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712609/stanford-parser-traversing-the-typed-dependencies-graph)
3. Use a semantic-role-labeler as indicated by Daniel in his answer.

I would recommend to try options 2,1,3 in that order.